# How to transfer this into codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Everthing is working I've tested it, my only problem is that how to transfer into Codeigniter.. please someone help and explain if can.. I have to add this on my school project but in Codeigniter framework. I'm newbie on Codeigniter and I want to learn more.

This is my "print.php"

```
    <?php
    require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
    if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  
    {  
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "datedate");
  $output = '';    
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_order WHERE order_date BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."'  ";  
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

  $pdf = new FPDF();


  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
  $pdf->Cell(50,10,'Date:'.date('d-m-Y').'',0,"R");
  $pdf->Ln(15);
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
  $pdf->Cell(0,10,'USERS',1,1,"C");
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
  $pdf->Cell(10,8,'No.',1);
  $pdf->Cell(45,8,'First Name',1);
  $pdf->Cell(45,8,'Middle Name',1);
  $pdf->Cell(45,8,'Last Name',1);
  $pdf->Cell(45,8,'Birth Date',1);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
  {

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $no=$no+1;

$pdf->Ln(8);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->Cell(10,8,$no,1);
$pdf->Cell(45,8,$row['order_customer_name'],1);
$pdf->Cell(45,8,$row['order_item'],1,0,"C");
$pdf->Cell(45,8,$row['order_value'],1);
$pdf->Cell(45,8,$row['order_date'],1);
}
}
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

this is my "index.php"

```
    <?php  
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "datedate");  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_order ORDER BY order_id asc";  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
    ?>  
    <!DOCTYPE html>  
    <html>  
    <head>  
       <title>Ajax PHP MySQL Date Range Search using jQuery DatePicker</title>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <br /><br />  
       <div class="container" style="width:900px;">  
            <h2 align="center">Ajax PHP MySQL Date Range Search using jQuery DatePicker</h2>  
            <h3 align="center">Order Data</h3><br />  
            <div class="col-md-3">  
                 <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date" />  
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-3">  
                 <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" />  
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-5">  
                 <input type="button" name="filter" id="filter" value="Filter" class="btn btn-info" />  
            </div>  
            <div style="clear:both"></div>                 
            <br />  
            <div id="order_table">  
                 <table class="table table-bordered">  
                      <tr>  
                           <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                           <th width="30%">Customer Name</th>  
                           <th width="43%">Item</th>  
                           <th width="10%">Value</th>  
                           <th width="12%">Order Date</th>  
                      </tr>  
                 <?php  
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                 {  
                 ?>  
                      <tr>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["order_id"]; ?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["order_customer_name"]; ?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["order_item"]; ?></td>  
                           <td>$ <?php echo $row["order_value"]; ?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $row["order_date"]; ?></td>  
                      </tr>  
                 <?php  
                 }  
                 ?>  
                 </table>  
            </div>  
       </div>  
  </body>  
  </html>  
  <script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){  
       $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'   
       });  
       $(function(){  
            $("#from_date").datepicker();  
            $("#to_date").datepicker();  
       });  
       $('#filter').click(function(){  
            var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
            var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  
            if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
            {  
                 $.ajax({  
                      url:"print.php",  
                      method:"POST",  
                      data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},  
                      success:function(data)  
                      {  
                           $('#order_table').html(data);  
                      }  
                 });  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                 alert("Please Select Date");  
            }  
       });  
  });  
  </script>
```

Comment: just convert simple query to active record query and controller view model things

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code conversion tool

Comment: how? Just a beginner here.. you mean on model right? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I mean how to transfer this on Codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is currently in pure PHP, and you want to code it in CodeIgniter, right?
If so, please take a look at it's document. Or sample here: [This link](https://selftaughtcoders.com/creating-processing-form-codeigniter/)

I suggest your code will like this:

In `models/order.php`

```
Class Order {
    public function detail($id) {
        // Get and return your data here
    }
}
```

In controllers/index.php

```
Class IndexController {
    public function index() {
        // load model here
        $data = ... // call to Order->detail
        // Return view here
    }
}
```

In views/index.php

```
// Render your view, form here
```

In `controllers/print.php`

```
Class Print {
    public function index() {
        // Do your code after submit here
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.